# Test release build without uploading to Playstore after signing

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-console

I am using Cordova to create Android Application.
Problem : I am using [Cordova Plugin Update Notififer](https://github.com/AyogoHealth/cordova-plugin-update-notifier) . In debug version, even after downloading the update, App Restarts and again ask to update. It never actually update the app but just keep asking to download the latest version as Update is available.

I was thinking may be it's because of signing, As I am using debug version and trying to get updates from play store. So Is there is any way to test release version without uploading to play store? Currently I get "App not installed Error" when I try to install release version on Device .
I am so sorry, I am not so good in Programming

Comment: What you described, will work. Just make sure that you actually sign your release build.

Comment: It actually does not work as it says, App not installed !

Comment: Do you still have the debug version installed? If yes, delete it first.

Comment: I deleted that first already